# Using a Try with no catch and no finally

Tags: try-catch, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to follow an example from a source called "Baeldung" where they show how to do a Json post request with HttpURLConnection.  Part of the example is the following code snippet ...

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String responseLine = null;
    while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(responseLine.trim());
    }
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

This code is using a try with no catch or no finally.  I didn't know that was possible.  What is going on here?  What happens if an exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReader will be always closed automatically  because it implements AutoCloseable and initalialized in try statement. all exceptions will be passed to calling function

check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html